# How to merge cells into a single one with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: picture of DataFrame]

I'm trying to 'merge' the item section into a list according to the Transaction ID. So, I want Chocolate Quente and Jam on a list.

Comment: this is a simple groupby `df.groupby('id').agg(items=('item',list), date=('date','unique'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby('Transaction')['Item'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's better to include some context around it, so future readers can be helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following: `item_list=df[df["Transaction"]==3]["Item"].to_list()` or `list(df[df["Transaction"]==3]["Item"]`

I suppose this should work if 3 is an int type. If it's an object (string), use double quotes "3".